# Get value from a dynamic url

Tags: python, regex

My url looks like:

```
http://www.example.com/blah/prod/4/x/blah.html
```

Now if this page has sub-pages, it will look like:

http://www.example.com/blah/prod/4_2343/x/blah.html

i.e. after /prod/4  there will be a underscore than another number.

Again if this page has sub-pages, it will be:

http://www.example.com/blah/prod/4_2343_234/x/blah.html

**I need to get all the text that I put ??? below:**

/prod/???????/x/blah.html

how can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example like this. A regexp that matches the pattern prod/???/x/blah, where ??? is any string consisting of numbers and underscores:

```
import re
pattern = re.compile('prod/([\d_]+)/x/blah')
query   = "http://www.example.com/blah/prod/4_2343_234/x/blah.html"
result  = pattern.search(query).group(1)
print result
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import urlparse
url = 'http://www.example.com/blah/prod/4_2343_234/x/blah.html'

urlparse.urlsplit(url).path.split('/')[3]
# returns '4_2343_234'
```